# ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database <MyDB>

Tags: sql-server

I have a program need to create and drop a database multiple time, but sometime when dropping a database I get a exception here:

```
ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database ...
```

And the command is like this:

```
USE master; 

IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='{0}')

BEGIN 

ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

DROP DATABASE [{0}]

END
```

Why it happens?

What is the better way to do this (drop database)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't `DROP` a database if any one else is connected to it. Simply running `DROP DATABASE MyDatabase;` doesn't close those connections, thus the `DROP` fails.

Changing the database to `SINGLE USER` will drop any existing connections (`WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` causes any transactions to be rolled back immediately, which is a problem here, as your about the `DROP` the database). Then, because it's instantly the next statement, the database is dropped before anyone gets the opportunity to reconnect.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but why the SQL command sometimes works? And it is a recommended way to drop a database from others' suggestion, I just copy paste that.

Comment: @AllenS Why does what sometimes work? Just `DROP DATABASE Mydatabase;`? Probably because no one is connected to the database.

Comment: I updated my question, and I mean this exception does not occurs every time drop the database in the program.